# Getting the full url for an webpage

Tags: asp.net

On on aspx.page On the code behind I want the full uri of another web page! Is there some standard function!

So say i am on

```
http:\\test.us\dir1\link1.aspx
```

In this page i want to get the full URI based on relative url

> GetFullUri("~\dir2\link2.aspx")
>
> Then returned is
>
> http:\test.us\dir2\link2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function which takes the relative path is input and then based on the current URL it return the full path. Do not pass ~ as rel in the method

```
       URL used for this example:
       http://localhost:12345/site/page.aspx?q1=1&q2=2

       Value of HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
       localhost

       Value of HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority
       localhost:12345

       Value of HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
       /site/page.aspx

       Value of HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath
       /site

       Value of HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
       http://localhost:12345/site/page.aspx?q1=1&q2=2

       static string (HttpContext context , string rel)
       {
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + rel;
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for youre reply! why should i not pass the ~

Comment: ~ is not part of URL you need .